# turn off automatically closing tag in aptana studio3

Tags: ide, aptana

I'm using Aptana for rails development IDE. For one thing that keep annoying me, I can't find the configuration where it allows me to turn off auto-closing of ruby method (def/end) tag.

I did manage to turn HTML tag closing off under preference->aptana->editor->html->automatically insert closing tags, but not with the ruby code.

anyone could give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to preferences > editors > HTML, there is an option for auto-closing tags. Uncheck this and it will stop auto-closing.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Auto-close matching character pairs" in the preferences as shown in the picture. This turns off auto-insert of quotation marks, parentheses and square brackets.

[image]